# Define an nxn matrix A by a(i,j)=-1+2max(i,j) and b(j)=sum(j to n) a(i,j). Then test Naive-Gauss on this system (Matlab)

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

Testing the system using Naive Gauss is the easy part but I am having trouble being able to define A and b. The code I have right now is the following:

```
A=zeros(n);


for i=1:n

    for j=1:n
        smax=max(i,j);
        A(i,j)=-1+2*smax;
    end
end

for j=1:n

    sum=0;
    sum=sum+A(i,j);
    b(j)=sum;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition of `b` is not clear. What is the value of `i` within the sum?

Assuming the sum is extended over all `i`:

```
n = 5; %// matrix size. Set as needed
[ii jj] = ndgrid(1:n);
A = -1+2*max(ii,jj);
b = sum(fliplr(cumsum(fliplr(A),2)));
```